# Solving $\sin x+\sin 2x+\sin 3x=1+\cos x +\cos 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I had a math test today and I had this problem and I couldn't solve it!!!
I hope you could show me how to do it, here it is:

$$\sin x+\sin 2x+\sin 3x=1+\cos x +\cos 2x$$

Is there any simple way to do this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\sin(x)+\sin(3x)=2\sin(2x)\cos(x)$$ and $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1,$$one has
$$\begin{align}\\&2\sin(2x)\cos(x)+\sin(2x)=1+\cos(x)+2\cos^2(x)-1\\&\iff \sin(2x)(2\cos(x)+1)=\cos(x)(2\cos(x)+1)\\&\iff (2\cos(x)+1)(\sin(2x)-\cos(x))=0\\&\iff (2\cos(x)+1)(2\sin(x)\cos(x)-\cos(x))=0\\&\iff \cos(x)(2\cos(x)+1)(2\sin(x)-1)=0\end{align}$$
I think you can take it from here.

Comment: How did you know to do all of that?!!

Comment: @LiziPizi: Trial and error. I tried to replace $3x$ with "smaller" ones (2x or x).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the equation is equivalent to $$\cos \left( x \right)  \left( 2\,\cos \left( x \right) +1 \right) 
 \left( 2\,\sin \left( x \right) -1 \right)
=0$$